# Python iterating through a tuple within a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I currently have a list of characters defined in a dictionary:

```
characters = {'Tom':['Brown Hair', 'Brown Eyes'],
'Dick':['Brown Hair', 'Blue Eyes'],
'Harry':['Blonde Hair', 'Brown Eyes'],
'Joe':['Blonde Hair', 'Blue Eyes']}
```

I randomly generate an attribute to be checked against the values in the dictionary. If the attribute is not contained anywhere in the value assigned to key then it gets deleted. If it is then the key doesn't get deleted. I have tried this:

```
def one_turn(self):
   for a, b in self.characters.items():
       if self.att not in self.answer:
           if self.att in b:
                del self.characters[a]
       else:
           if self.att not in b:
                del self.characters[a]
```

When self.att is assigned to an attribute it will iterate through the value list one by one, whereas I wanted it all to be checked before a decision is made whether to delete or not.

Cheers

Comment: could you explain what you mean by "I wanted it all to be checked before a decision is made". Also does your characters dict ever change/update?

Comment: Please include example input and expected output, as well as the full traceback of the exception you get. You can reduce the code to not rely on `self` (passing in the `self.[attrname]` values in as function arguments instead, making your example just that bit more minimal.

Comment: That said, you can't iterate over a dictionary and at the same time delete keys from it. There are techniques to use instead, but without a clear problem description and expected output we can't begin to pick the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to a list to keep track of the presence (or absence) of the values:

```
def one_turn(self):
   missing_list = []
   for a, b in self.characters.items():
       if self.att not in self.answer:
           if self.att in b:
                missing_list.append(a)
       else:
           if self.att not in b:
               missing_list.append(a)

    # now delete all relevant characters
    for key in missing_list:
        del self.characters[key]
```

I hope I understood your intent correctly...